# liquibase returns false positive results for DiffChangeLog

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I am moving PostgreSQL 9.6 from on-prem to RDS Aurora PostgreSQL 11.4.

First step, used pg_dump to export database metadata (with over 700 schemas).

Next, wanted to verify I am not missing any constraints, objects and that source and database are aligned.

Using Liquibase with DiffChangeLog gives false positive results like:

- Dropping constraints from target when they exists on source.
- Create view when it exists with identical source code in source and target.

Here is the Liquibase command for a single schema.
I had to script over 700 for all schemas in the database:

```
c:\> liquibase.bat ^
--changeLogFile=d:\users\compare\changelog.postgresql.sql ^
--outputFile=d:\users\compare\Database_diff.txt ^
--classpath="D:\Program Files\liquibase\postgresql-42.2.12.jar" ^
--driver=org.postgresql.Driver ^
--url=jdbc:postgresql://<source_endpoint>:5432/<source_database> ^
--username=<source_username> ^
--password=<source_password> ^
--defaultSchemaName=<source_schema> ^
--includeSchema=true ^
DiffChangeLog ^
--referenceUrl=jdbc:postgresql://<target_endpoint>:5432/<target_databas> ^
--referenceUsername=<target_username> ^
--referencePassword=<target_password> ^
--referenceDefaultSchemaName=<target_schema>
```

Please advise how to avoid false positive results.

Comment: If you already use Liquibase, then why don't you apply your Liquibase changelog to the new server? Or just dump your current database and import it into the new one?

Comment: I used pg_dump and created the new database with this dump. I just want to verify using Liquibase that during pg_dump/pg_restore nothing got lost in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You also might try flipping the url and reference url.
diffChangeLog will use referenceUrl as the reference or the source of the way you want the database to look.  And will use url as the target for your changes.